# How to provide an Facebook app review screencast for an app with no UI?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I’m trying to automate creation of ad accounts for my own business, and then upload custom audiences into these ad accounts. I wish to do this using a system user.

I have written some scripts to automate this process, but I am unsure how to receive the appropriate permissions from Facebook as I can not create a screencast, as my scripts has no UI. It’s just a collection of scripts.

Some research has a said that if apps only talk to a small number of accounts, you can just leave apps in dev mode to avoid going through app review, but I don’t think that’s possible in this case for the following reasons.

When my app is in dev mode, and I try to `POST` to `https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/<my-business-id>/adaccount` to create a new ad account in my business, I get the error: `"(#270) Development access is not allowed to access business API post:Business/adaccount.”` OK. So my app has to be live for me to use this end point. If I set my app to Live, and then try to hit this end point, I get this error `"(#294) Managing advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission for ads_management”`

Then, looking at the permissions screen in my app, it appears I need to submit an app review with a screencast to be able to use the `ads_management` permission.

Additionally, if I want to use a system user, I can only approve permissions that have been approved by the app review process.

Given that my app has no UI (and nothing to screencast) how should I proceed? Or am I missing a way to do this without going through the app review process?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook as provided instructions on how to submit those kinds of apps here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps:

> If your app has no user interface because it exchanges data directly with our APIs, refer to this guide when configuring your app's Basic Settings, and when completing App Review.